# Using if statement with ArcPy and GetCount?

Tags: arcpy, count, if-else

I am looking to get a count on the polygonNieghbor and if it has polygons in it then I want to move to the next step MakeFeatureLayer. and If it doesn't have any features I would like it to finish.

Is there any other way to do this?

```
arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect)
arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())

if arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect) > 0:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(MapUnitPolys, inFeatures_lyr)
 else
     print "done"
```

Answer (score 7):

All geoprocessing tools produce a [Results](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/result.htm) object. You want the first output of your `GetCount` results object. The output will be a string, so you also must convert the string to an integer.

`if int (arcpy.GetCount_management(PolygonNeighbor_TableSelect) [0]) > 0:`